# How to set error message window size?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How to show complete message in the pop-up error window? sample:[image]

```
error "convergency_check_start should be larger than 3."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get the full error message if you'll increase the error window size. The message is truncated deliberately. You could look into `bgerror.tcl` inside your Tk library folder just to find that the error message lines are truncated at 45 characters.

What you could do is override the `::tk::dialog::error::bgerror` procedure. And since totally rewriting it is too tedious, I'd suggest to patch it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

set eproc ::tk::dialog::error::bgerror
auto_load $eproc
proc $eproc [info args $eproc] [string map {45 150} [info body $eproc]]

after idle {
    error "Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
}
```

This code replaces `45` by `150` in the body of `::tk::dialog::error::bgerror` and shows the whole error message in the window. Without `[string map ...]` only about a half of the message is displayed imemdiately (you can still see all the mesage with a stack trace after clicking the `Details >>` button).

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks very much!

Comment: Note however that there's little that is more frustrating than an error dialog so wide that the edges of it are off the screen. Also, there's _nothing_ wrong with using a custom dialog for your application; the default has to handle so many different use cases that it can't be ideal for any of them.